# in WSL, why "[]$ cd /mnt" works, but "[mnt]$ cd /c" gives error?

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL - Why is leading `mnt` with a slash, okay, but leading `c` (after being in the mnt directory) with a slash gives an error (No such file or directory)?

```
diego@DESKTOP:/$ cd /mnt
diego@DESKTOP:/mnt$ cd /c
-bash: cd: /c: No such file or directory
diego@DESKTOP:/mnt$
```

btw - I know typing `c` only or `mnt` only would work, but I want to understand why is there a difference between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `/` means filesystem root, so you can't use it to change current directory to relative path.

Read more about [root directory here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/the-root-directory.html)

In your case, you can do

`cd /mnt
cd c`

or

`cd /mnt/c`